# Google Cloud unable to share file publicly

Tags: cloud, share, public

As of this morning a file uploaded to my bucket on Google Cloud cannot be marked to be shared publicly.  The Public Link checkbox is not enabled.  I tried clicking on another file that had previously had the Public Link checkbox checked.  Doing so unchecked the checkbox and now that one is also not enabled, and no longer accessible over the web.

I clicked on the Share Publicly link on the top and now that is grayed out and not enabled.

Is Google just broken?  There doesn't seem to be anyone to call or email when their product breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it was, Google seems to have fixed it.  After several hours, it suddenly works as expected again.